# How to Syncrhonize designer.cs and xib file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin iOS in visual studio and sometimes I have a bug that commits my work: I add a View using "Add New Item" > "ViewController" and edit xib file, but sometimes, the xib file don't synchronize with the designer file, in other words, when I add a Label, for example and set a Name, the designer file don't add a Label property.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problems. My workaround is to migrate to Mac, install Parallels for Windows (optional) and use Visual Studio for code editing and Xamarin Studio (you can right click on xib and open it with Interface Builder - native Xcode editor) for xib editing.

One more important thing: just saving xib via File/Save is not enough, you also **have to close Xcode** in order changes to be saved.